# shuffling randomly objects/arrays in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, shuffle

i have a quiz questions set. i want to randomly pick 5 questions every time. any idea on how to do this. 
this is the questions data

```
export const Quizdata = [
  {
    id: 0,
    question:
      "If you see this sign on a gate or farm entrance what should you do?",
    options: [
      "You should never enter the area where this sign is displayed",
      "You can enter the area, if you know there is no bull present",
      "Sometimes, these signs are wrong. So it is OK to enter if you take care",
      "Most bulls are tame farm pets. You just have to take care"
    ],
    answer: "You should never enter the area where this sign is displayed",
    picture: <img src={Pic} id="pic1" alt="" />
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    question:
      "If you see this symbol on a bottle or container what does it mean?",
    options: [
      "This symbol tells you that the contents of the bottle or container are hazardous and are very dangerous to humans and animals. You should not touch this bootle or container",
      "This symbol is the logo or symbol for famous brands of chemicals",
      "This symbol is the international symbol for weed killer spray",
      "This symbol tells you that the contents of the bottle or container are hazardour and are very dangerous to animals only"
    ],
    answer:
      "This symbol tells you that the contents of the bottle or container are hazardous and are very dangerous to humans and animals. You should not touch this bootle or container",
    picture: <img src={Pic2} alt="" id="pic2" />
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    question:
      "If you see this symbol on a bottle or container what does it mean?",
    options: [
      "This symbol tells you that there is electricity flowing in a system",
      "This symbol tells you that a machine has very dangerous blades or knives which can harm you",
      "This symbol tells you that a food or liquid is out of date",
      "This symbol tells you that this is a biological hazard and it is a serious threat to the health of all living things"
    ],
    answer:
      "This symbol tells you that this is a biological hazard and it is a serious threat to the health of all living things",
    picture: <img src={Pic3} alt="" id="pic3" />
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    question: " Why should children not play with this piece of equipment?",
    options: [
      "It is a boring toy",
      "This ratchet strap has many moving parts and it can cause damage to fingers and hands",
      "This isn't a piece of farm machinery equipment",
      "It doesn't work outside"
    ],
    answer:
      "This ratchet strap has many moving parts and it can cause damage to fingers and hands",
    picture: <img src={Pic4} alt="" id="pic4" />
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    question:
      "What age must you be in Ireland to drive a quad (all terrain vehicle) on a public road?",
    options: ["21 years old", "12 years old", "14 years old", "16 years old"],
    answer: "16 years old",
    picture: <img src={Pic5} alt="" id="pic5" />
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    question: "what should you do?",
    options: ["dont enter", "43", "all fine"],
    answer: "43",
    picture: ""
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    question: "what should you do?",
    options: ["dont enter", "set", "all fine"],
    answer: "set",
    picture: ""
  }
```

this is how i load in the quiz  in the component did mount

```
loadQuiz = () => {
    const { currentQuest } = this.state;
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        questions: Quizdata[currentQuest].question,
        options: Quizdata[currentQuest].options,
        answer: Quizdata[currentQuest].answer,
        pictures: Quizdata[currentQuest].picture
      };
    });
    console.log(this.state.answer);
  };
```

i want it randomly pick 5 questions not repeated and display one by one. in this sandbox i have the working of how the existing questions load .https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-saha-411y3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: the shuffling works but i want shuffle just 5 of the 10Qs i want to return only 5 questions that are shuffled @HereticMonkey

Comment: So pick questions until you've picked 5...

Comment: how do u do that ur just giving plain english answer can i see some examples??????????

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic but you need to ensure to take a copy of original array to another array so that your original set of questions are intact like this `newQuestions = [...questions]`.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

var newArray = [];
for(let i=0; i<5; i++) {
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length);
  newArray.push(myArray[index]);
  myArray.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(newArray);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: my issue is the question has 10 questoin i want n random quiz questions i need to export it out after can u look at my sandbox.https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-saha-411y3 and see its much harder to implement it

Comment: This logic also randomly picks 5 items in the array without repetition. Ya i will look at the sanboxcode.

Comment: The code is little confusing. I did not get what u are trying to achieve. You want to show only 5 questions to user and if all 5 questions are right, user will be taken to next level where he will be shown next 5 questions?